# how do i remove the background in a transparent material

Tags: materials, transparency, fluid-simulation

[image: water domain with flow]
i am working on a water simulation i am using evee, and not cycles as the scene doesn't require that much refinement, i have trhe transparecny figued out i think, how do i get rid of theforest back ground thar seems to be attached to the water material? (this is mantaflows water material), but i get the same result when i create a transparent material, what am i missing??? please help as this is stopping me from completing my first animated short. thanking any hepl in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot you are looking at the scene in Material Preview mode, so a temporarily HDR image is lighting the scene and gets reflected by the water material.

You can activate the Scene Lights and Scene World option to see the lighting that will be used in render.

[image]

If in Rendered mode there's still an unwanted reflection on the water material, open a shader editor window, switch from Object to World and disconnect the Output node, so to light the scene with light objects only.

[image]

Comment: I guess in _Material Preview_ and maybe even in _Render_ view (if _EEVEE_ is used) there will also be the problem of reflection/refraction etc. not working as expected by default.

Comment: thank you so much, i think with the settiing recommended fro evee reflection i should be goos with this update.

Comment: thank you so much